# how to use --generate-annotations parameters on Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using Doctrine to generate Entites from the database,

```
 vendor/bin/doctrine orm:convert-mapping --from-database yml configuration/yaml
```

i successfully exported into Yaml then I generated the entities with

```
 vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities entities/
```

I saw that the annotations were not complete but I also saw that there was a parameter `--generate-annotations`

I used the command line:

```
 vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities --generate-annotations entities/
```

but I get the error:

```
 [RuntimeException]
  Not enough arguments.
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the command  line this way :

```
vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities --generate-annotations=1 entities/
```

Just set annotations=1 or annotations="true"